# Blazor Textarea update on variable change

Tags: c#, blazor

I want a textarea to always show the value of a variable. But it only updates if I click a button. What can I do to update the textarea everytime the variable changes?

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="Test">Test</button>
<textarea  type="text" name="configJson" id="configJson"  value="@inputString" rows="20" cols="50" />
@code {
private string inputString;
    private void Test()
    {
        inputString = inputString;
    }
}
```

I have code that changes the variable constantly but it does not update the textarea. The textarea is only updated if I click the button. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is `StateHasChanged()` method of `ComponentBase` class.
This tells Blazor the data bindings (including one directional) needs updating.
BTW, why are you using "value" attribute of `textarea` element? You should set its content. It is not `input`. See the example below:

```cs
@page "/"

<textarea>
  @Text
</textarea>

@code {

    public string Text { get; set; }
    int Counter { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized() {
        base.OnInitialized();
        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => {
            Counter++;
            InvokeAsync(() => {
                Text = $"Tick {Counter}";
                StateHasChanged();
            });
        };
        timer.Start();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you this was all I needed to know =) Works like a charm.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using the value attribute instead of the content of the textarea. It is intuitive, it is consistent with the other input elements, and it works perfectly well. This is Blazor. This is not Html. Even the Forms InputTextArea  component binds to the value attribute instead of binding to the content --> https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/InputTextArea.cs

Comment: @enet: If this behaves different from HTML - it is inconsistent. I know, built in Blazor components like `InputText` can and should behave different - it is expected. We KNOW they are not HTML elements. They are in fact - components, as the name implies - composed of different parts. When you hide implied, non-obvious interface under a common, well-known name of well known HTML element - it is just bad design, it will lead to confusion and mistakes.